# Scaling ActiveMQ on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, activemq-classic, amazon-elb, autoscaling

First of all my knowledge of ActiveMQ, AMQPS and AWS auto scaling is fairly limited and I have been handed over this task where I need to create a scalable broker architecture for messaging over AMQPS using ActiveMQ.

In my current architecture if have a single machine ActiveMQ broker where the messaging is happening over AMQP + SSL and as a need of the product there is a publisher subscriber authentication (TLS authentication) to ensure correct guys are talking to each other. That part is working fine.

Now the problem is that I need to scale the whole broker thing over AWS cloud with auto-scaling in my mind. Without auto-scaling, I assume I can create a master slave architecture using EC2 instances, but then adding more slaves will be more like a manual process than automatic.

I want to understand wether below two options can solve the purpose -

- ELB + ActiveMQ nodes being auto scaled
- Something like a Bitnami powered ActiveMQ AMI running with auto scaling enabled.

In first case where ELB is there, I understand that ELB terminates SSL which will fail my mutual authentication. Also I am not sure wether my Pub/Sub model will still work where different ActiveMQ instances are independently running with no shared DB as such. If yes, if anyone can offer a pointer or a reference material it will be a help as I am not able to find one by myself.

In second case again, my concern is that when multiple instances are running with ActiveMQ how they will coordinate between each other and ensure that everyone has access to data being held up in queue.

The questions may be lame, but if any pointer it will be helpful.

AJ

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with activemq to provide a full answer, but your point about SSL termination at the ELB isn't necessarily true. If you configure the ELB listener as a TCP pass-through then you can terminate SSL at the server.

Comment: Point take Mark B about SSL relay with TCP pass-through. I checked that found it a possibility.